# i2c sensor data read using Ada on Microbit V1

Tags: ada

Is there an example of how to read data from the i2c sensor using Ada? I am using Microbit v1 for programming. I have an example of communication between Arduino and Microbit using i2c given here.

```
--  Request a character from the I2C slave and
--  display it on the 5x5 display in a loop.

with HAL.I2C;          use HAL.I2C;
with MicroBit.Display; use MicroBit.Display;
with MicroBit.I2C;
with MicroBit.Time;

procedure Main is
   Ctrl   : constant Any_I2C_Port := MicroBit.I2C.Controller;
   Addr   : constant I2C_Address := 16;
   Data   : I2C_Data (0 .. 0);
   Status : I2C_Status;
begin

   MicroBit.I2C.Initialize (MicroBit.I2C.S100kbps);
   if MicroBit.I2C.Initialized then
      --  Successfully initialized I2C
      Display ('I');  
   else
      --  Error initializing I2C
      Display ('E');  
   end if;
   MicroBit.Time.Delay_Ms (2000);
   MicroBit.Display.Clear;

   loop
      --  Request a character
      Ctrl.Master_Receive (Addr => Addr, Data => Data, Status => Status);

      --  Display the character or the error
      if Status = Ok then
         Display (Character'Val (Data (0)));
      else
         MicroBit.Display.Display (Status'Image);
      end if;

      --  Give the user time to read the display
      MicroBit.Time.Delay_Ms (1000);
      MicroBit.Display.Clear;
      MicroBit.Time.Delay_Ms (250);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

How can I tweak it to read data from the sensor and write data to an external OLED display

Comment: It's not entirely clear what mean by "the sensor" and "an OLED display". How data can be read from a sensor and must be written to an OLED display device differs per product. You need to consult the product's datasheet for protocol details and, based on that, write some driver that handles these details. You may, however, be lucky that a driver for the sensor and display you want to use already exist. See, for example, [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/Ada_Drivers_Library/tree/master/components/src). If not, then the drivers listed in the link may serve as an example for writing your own.

Comment: Is the code you show the code you want to get working? does it run? if not, how not? if it does run, what do you expect it to do? what does it actually do? (I’m not addressing the OLED display yet, that would be a whole different ball game)